# OpenGL ES2.0 rotate camera around its axis

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need to rotate the camera around its axis by degrees. How can this be realized? I can not formulate a formula by which to calculate new lookX, lookY, lookZ. I will be very grateful for the help!

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
```

Video just in case: [Video](https://congard.pp.ua/files/camera_rotating.mp4)

Comment: I think I've found a solution. If eyeZ - lookZ = 1, then the equality: look[X or Y] = tan (angle). If you need to look back, then eyeZ - lookZ = -1.

Comment: Note: it is if center in x = 0 and y = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was:

```
float deltaZ = 4; // for example 4, it can be any number
oglr.angleX += (downX-x)/10;
oglr.angleY += (y-downY)/10;
if (oglr.angleX > 90 && oglr.angleX < 270) oglr.lookZ = oglr.eyeZ + deltaZ;
else oglr.lookZ = oglr.eyeZ - deltaZ;
if (oglr.angleX < 0) oglr.angleX = 360+oglr.angleX;
if (oglr.angleX > 360) oglr.angleX = oglr.angleX%360;
oglr.lookX = oglr.eyeZ > oglr.lookZ ? (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(oglr.angleX))*(oglr.eyeZ-oglr.lookZ) + oglr.eyeX : (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(oglr.angleX-180))*(oglr.eyeZ-oglr.lookZ) + oglr.eyeX;
oglr.lookY = (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(oglr.angleY))*(Math.abs(oglr.eyeZ-oglr.lookZ)) + oglr.eyeY;
downX = x;
downY = y;
```

Note: oglr - OpenGLRenderer; x, y - MotionEvent.getX() and getY()